# Celery. Decrease number of processes

Tags: python, django, celery

Is there any way around to limit number of workers in [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)? I have small server and celery always creates 10 processes on 1 core processor. I want to limit this number to 3 processes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I tried setting concurrency to 1 and max_tasks_per_child to 1 in my settings.py file and ran 3 tasks at the same time. It just spawns 1 process as a User and the other 2 as celery. It should should just run 1 process and then wait for it to finish before running the other one.

I am using django celery.

**EDIT** {

I was assigning concurrency by writing CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1 in settings.py file. But when I looked at the celery log file using "tail -f /var/log/celery/w1.log" then I saw a value of 8 assigned to concurrency. This told me that setting.py does not change the concurrency. 
To fix this issue I added the following lines to "/etc/default/celeryd" file.

```
# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--concurrency=1"
```

Now the second task in the queue waits until the first is finished.

}

Comment: I agree on 3 processes, but for me it spawns 10 always.

Comment: I only tried three processes. I don't know the limit though. The main thing is that if concurrency is 1 why are the subsequent tasks even running. They should be on the hold.

Comment: Wow! Editing `/etc/default/celeryd` helped me! Thank you very much! =)

Answer (score 10):

celery worker **--concurrency** option allows to specify the number of child processes processing the queue.

Comment: `CELERYD_CONCURENCY = 1` not working - still spawns 10 processes. And **--concurrency=1** has same effect.

Comment: Have you tried to kill all python processes before launching? May be they are old or unrelated processes.

Comment: --autoscale=1,1 don't help.. very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my celeryd-config file

```
CELERYD_NODES=2
```

which results in

```
$ ps -ef | grep "celery" | grep -v "grep"
www-data  1783     1  0 17:50 ?        00:00:46 /usr/bin/python /opt/webapps/repo/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO -n celery1.xxx-31-39-06-74-75 --logfile=/var/log/celery/1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/1.pid 
www-data  1791  1783  0 17:50 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /opt/webapps/repo/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO -n celery1.xxx-31-39-06-74-75 --logfile=/var/log/celery/1.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/1.pid
www-data  1802     1  0 17:50 ?        00:00:52 /usr/bin/python /opt/webapps/repo/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO -n celery2.xxx-31-39-06-74-75 --logfile=/var/log/celery/2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/2.pid 
www-data  1858  1802  0 17:50 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /opt/webapps/repo/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO -n celery2.xxx-31-39-06-74-75 --logfile=/var/log/celery/2.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/2.pid
```

There are FOUR processes, not two, but there are two workers.  It looks like each worker thread has two processes.  So presumably if you set CELERYD_NODES to 3, you will get 3 workers but 6 processes.

Comment: Ignores for me this option. CELERYD_NODES = 1 results in 10 processes. CELERYD_NODES = 2 results in 10 processes.

Answer (score 0):

You should try --autoscale=3 in the celery option params.