# celery always has 3 processes, why?

Tags: django, celery, mysql-python

I run the crawler application with celery(version 3.1) tasks and django(version 1.6.5. using its orm). And the command is:

```
celery -A crawlerproj worker -P gevent -c 1000 -l info
```

by using the 'htop' in Ubuntu, I see that celery always has 3 processes. And there are 5 more mysqldb processes. I don't know why. Can numbers of celery and mysqldb decrease?

My vps has 1G Memory and 1 core. Here is the snapshot of the htop result.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213665/celery-decrease-number-of-processes ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `celery` starts as many worker processes as it thinks you have processors/cores/threads: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html

> If you’re doing mostly I/O you can have more processes, but if mostly CPU-bound,
>   try to keep it close to the number of CPUs on your machine. If not set, the number of 
>   CPUs/cores on the host will be used.

Comment: but my vps just have 1 core. so you mean my vps have 3CPU?

Comment: I don't know how Celery guesses the number of CPUs/cores/threads for a VPS. In any case, you can easily change the default as shown in the docs.

Comment: And I have another question to ask. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955798/can-celerys-beat-tasks-execute-at-timed-intervals