# Can celery's beat tasks execute at timed intervals?

Tags: celery

This is the beat tasks setting:

```
celery_app.conf.update(
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'taskA': {
    'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.manual_crawler_update',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},
'taskB': {
    'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.auto_crawler_update_day',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},
'taskC': {
    'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.auto_crawler_update_hour',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},
})
```

Normally taskA,taskB,taskC execute at the same time after my command `celery -A myproj beat` as the beat tasks. But now I want that taskA execute first,and then some time later taskB excute second,taskC excute at last.And after 3600 seconds they excute again.And after 3600 seconds they excute again.And after 3600 seconds they excute again. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. Create a chain for all three tasks and then use this chained task for scheduling.

In your `tasks.py` file:

```
from celery import chain
chained_task = chain(taskA, taskB, taskC)
```

Then schedule the `chained_task`:

```
celery_app.conf.update(
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'chained_task': {
    'task': 'crawlerapp.tasks.manual_crawler_update',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3600),
},  
})
```

By this, your task will execute in order once in 3600 seconds.

Comment: but I have 3 tasks functions: manual_crawler_update, auto_crawler_update_day, auto_crawler_update_hour.you mean that these 3 tasks are tasksA taskB taskC??

Comment: Yes, those 3 tasks can be anything as long as they have task decorator.

Comment: hi,can I ask you another question?Is it possible that I just stop the taskA,and at the same time,taskB and taskC is still work.Because when the taskA have bugs,I must stop the celery beat tasks together and then after I modify the bugs I start the beat tasks together.

Comment: I dont think its possible as the result of first task might affect the next task. Do checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461374/celery-stop-execution-of-a-chain

Comment: Just ignore the chains.I just have 3 tasks.They are not in a chain.

Comment: In that case, you can do it.

Comment: ok.I checkout the url first.thanks very much. Can we communicate about python web framework or some other python awesome app? My email is no13bus@gmail.com