# Celery : CELERYD_CONCURRENCY and number of workers

Tags: celery, django-celery, worker

From the [other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213665/celery-decrease-number-of-processes), I've tried to **limit celery's number of workers**

After I terminated all the celery worker, I restarted celery with new configuration.

`CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1` (in Django's *settings.py*)

Then I typed following command to check how many celery workers are working.

`ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`

It returns **two PIDs** like 24803, 24817.

Then I changed configuration to `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 2` and restarted celery.

Same command returns **three PIDs** like 24944, 24958, 24959. (*As you can see, last two PIDs are sequential*)

It implies that **number of workers** is increased as I expected.

However, I don't know **why it returns two PIDs even though there is only one celery worker is working?**

Is there a something *subsidiary process* to help worker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe one process always acts like the controller that listens for tasks and then distributes them to it's child processes to actually perform the work. Therefore, you will always have 1 more process than the configuration setting.

Comment: I think so. But I need reference data like documentation rather than 'thought'. Did you checked it on your server?

Comment: Here is a thread from the official forum where Ask Solem (the lead developer of Celery) explains that's the case:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/celery-users/eq3L5vxy_t4/KAkuXUqU9BcJ

Comment: A-ha! It seems to be `celery beat`, which executes some periodic tasks, is using the one of celery workers