# Non-periodic repetition of task in Django using celery

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I need to run a task "CreateNotifications" at random intervals of time.
Here is what I was trying to do in the settings for CELERY.

```
t = random.randint(45, 85)
## print "time = ", t

## celery app configuration
app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    # Executes at every 't' interval, where t is random
    'create-notifications': {
        'task': 'apps.notifications.tasks.CreateNotifications',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=t),
    },
}
```

Now the problem is that these settings for CELERY are executed only once (when I run the command python manage.py runserver), hence the variable 't' and hence the value of 'seconds' in timedelta gets a random value, but only once.

Ultimately making the above process a periodic one with a fixed period as X seconds, only X being selected at random when I start server.

Alternately I've tried running a single task and used an endless while loop in it with a random delay, so that celery autodetects only one task and that task never ends. My purpose is solved by random delay in the while loop.
Like this ( NOTE -> 'while' is inside the function CreateNotifications() )

```
@app.task
def CreateNotifications():

while True:

    upper_limit = models.MyUser.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id'))
    lower_limit = models.MyUser.objects.all().aggregate(Min('id'))

    ## select a user to be notified randomly

    to_user = None
    to = 0

    while to_user is None:
        to = random.randint(lower_limit['id__min'], upper_limit['id__max'])
        try:
            to_user = models.MyUser.objects.get(id=to)
        except:
            pass

    ## select a user to be notified from randomly

    frm_user = None
    frm = to

    while frm_user is None:
        while frm == to:
            frm = random.randint(lower_limit['id__min'], upper_limit['id__max'])
        try:
            frm_user = models.MyUser.objects.get(id=frm)
        except:
            pass

    notif_type = ['comment on', 'liked', 'shared']
    notif_media = ['post', 'picture', 'video']

    models.Notification.objects.create(
        notified_user = to_user,
        notifier = frm_user,
        notification_type = random.choice(notif_type),
        notification_media = random.choice(notif_media))

    to_user.new_notification_count += 1
    to_user.save()


    t = random.randint(35, 55)
    print "delay = ", t
    time.sleep(t)
```

Its doing things exactly as I want, but now there are 4 different workers executing the same task, but i want only one.

I've tried changes to celeryd file located in my virtualenv/bin/  directory as indicated here -> [Celery. Decrease number of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213665/celery-decrease-number-of-processes)

as there is no celeryd file in /etc/defaults/  but still no success

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't put an endless loop in a Celery task. If you need a dedicated process it would be better to run it on it's own rather than through Celery.

You could reschedule a new task in the future whenever your task runs. Something like the following:

```
@app.task
def create_notifications():
     try:
          #
     finally:
          t = random.randint(45, 85)
          create_notifications.apply_async(countdown=t)
```

Another option would be to have a scheduler task that runs on a regular schedule but queues the notification tasks for a random time in the near future. For example, if the scheduler task runs every 45 seconds.

```
@app.task
def schedule_notifications():
     t = random.randint(0, 40)
     create_notifications.apply_async(countdown=t)
```

Comment: Thanks @joshua. My mentor at my work place told me the same fix and it worked. Thanks anyhow for the answer. It is the correct way. And yes, endless loop should be avoided. While using the endless loop, I had to clear the celery queue everytime, to stop the tasks from executing by using CELERY PURGE..!! And those 4 workers working was due to the fact that i had called my CreateNotifications.apply_async() 4 times from shell and never cleared them from the queue.