# Limit number of processes in Celery with supervisor

Tags: celery, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I'm running Celery in a small instance in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

However, when I do `top`, I see there are 3 `celery` processes running. I want to have only.

I'm running this using `supervisor` and in my config file I have (only showing relevant lines):

```
[program:celeryd]
directory=/opt/python/current/app/src
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -A ..."

user=celery
numprocs=1
killasgroup=true
```

I've also followed the suggestion [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12217897/72350) and created a file `/etc/default/celeryd` with this content:

```
# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--concurrency=1"
```

After restarting Celery (with `supervisorctl -c config-file-path.conf restart celeryd`), I see the 3 processes again. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting worker with `celery` command. Changing `/etc/default/celeryd` won't have any effect on celery command. Moreover celeryd is deprecated.

When a worker is started, celery launches a default process and n(concurrency) subprocesses.

You can start the worker with

```
[program:celery]
command=/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery worker -c 1 -A foo"
```

This will start a worker with concurrency of 1 and there will be 2 processes.